# Fusion charts not working without Adobe Flash Player Activex:

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, fusioncharts

I am using Fusion charts in my web application. It was working fine. But I uninstalled Adobe Flash Player Activex. After that, the fusion charts are not working. How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check which FusionCharts version you are using. If you are using FusionCharts 3.2.2 (i.e. FusionCharts XT) the chart will be rendered in JavaScript automatically if you do not have Flash Player. However, if you have 3.2 or 3.2.1 you need to add a single line of code, to enable this:

```
FusionCharts._fallbackJSChartWhenNoFlash()
```

If you are having FusionCharts version lower to 3.2, you need to upgrade to make use of this feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hy! I'm using fusion charts 3.2.1 and id doesn't happen anything if I use that method when no flash is available... can you explain me, please, where do I have to put this line?

Comment: If you are using JavaScript code to render the chart, you can use detectFlashVersion and autoInstallRedirect constructor parameters (set them to 1) to show an alert message and a redirection to flash player download page.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972883/fusion-charts-show-no-flash-player-warning-message/9973553#9973553