# Fusion Charts show no flash player warning message

Tags: javascript, flash, fusioncharts

I'm using Fusion Charts 3.2.1. I want to show a warning message when my flash player isn't enabled in browser or installed. How do I do that? Is strange that even on the official site the chart panel is completely blank when flash is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript code to render the chart, you can use detectFlashVersion and autoInstallRedirect constructor parameters (set them to 1) to show an alert message and a redirection to flash player download page.

example:

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts({ swfUrl : "FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", id : "myChartId", renderAt : "chartContainer", dataSource : "Data.xml", "detectFlashVersion": 1, "autoInstallRedirect": 1 });
```

Check out the last two constructor properties.

or

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts("FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "myChartId", "400", "300", 0, 0, "", "noScale", "", 1, 1);
```

Check out the last two parameters (passed as 1) in the above code

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to customize the message? Perhaps showing a message in the chart's div and not a javascript alert?

Comment: @spauny, you can customize the alert message's text by `FusionCharts.options.installRedirectMessage = "Your own message!"`

Comment: Also, if you want to edit the URL to which redirection takes place, configure `FusionCharts.options.flashInstallerUrl = "http://yourdomain.com/path/"`

Comment: You can also use `FusionCharts.hasRequiredFlashVersion()` (available with latest FusionCharts JS Library) to check whether correct Flash version is enabled or not.

Comment: @sudimail, i dont know how to show fusion chart on android using flash. javascript fusion chart is working fine. can you show me any example how to integrate fusion charts with android using flash player. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's more than a year and the post is too old now compared to the speed in which technology is evolving. FusionCharts will soon not provide Flash charts. However, in case, you have earlier version of FusionCharts, preferably v3.1.1 or earlier, you can: using `var myChart = new FusionCharts("FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "myChartId", "400", "300", 0, 0, "", "noScale", "", 1, 1);` However, you need yo ensure your device has Flash Player installed. Additionally, you need to run this as JavaScript in an HTML container inside a browser component.

Comment: @sumitpandey: Also, I am not sure if you intend to show the chart through a browser or a native application.